# Accessing Friends List on new FB APIs for non-app users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-friends

I am building an app where users can send picture messages to friends and would like users to see their Facebook friends list when they login through FB. However, I am confused by Facebook's new API information regarding the access that an app can have to display someone's list of friends. On the FB change log information page it says:

1) Friend list is no longer part of the default permission set and has its own permission: Asking for access to a person's friend list is now a separate permission that your app must request. The new permission is called user_friends.
2) Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Does this mean that my app will only display to users their Friends that are also using my app? Is there no way for a User to see their entire friends list? And if not, how can I prompt the User to invite new friends to use my app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is exactly what it means, and for what you want to do there is no way to get the friends who did not authorize your App. But maybe you want to use the Send Dialog instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

For that, you don't even need to authorize the user and he can choose the receiver on his own.

Comment: Thank you for your response however, how would a User even know or see a Friend who doesn't have the app to send this message to if the API doesn't display them?

Comment: try the send dialog, the user can choose on his own from ALL his friends in that dialog